# Need to write filenames to a text file

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to VB Scripting and I am looking to see if there is a way to look at a directory get the file names and then write those file names to a text file. I would think that the Path.GetFileName Method would work, but I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe I am using it the wrong way.

Comment: What about sharing some code?

Comment: There is no Path object in VBScript. So start yout research here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: A very tiny effort (like looking in the Related list) yielded [Read and write into a file using VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1142678/62576) for the "write to file" part, and [Print out files in a directory sorted by FileName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209617/print-out-files-in-a-directory-sorted-by-filename) for the "getting filenames" part.

Comment: I dont need to print the documnets out, but thanks Dan was able to get me what I need. Thanks for the input from everyone. what books do you recommend reading for learning VB Scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script that will echo the filenames in the "C:\Windows\" directory.

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Log file name
Set logFile = fs.OpenTextFile("fileNameLogs.txt", 2, True)
'Directory you want listed
Set folder = fs.GetFolder("c:\windows\")

Set files = folder.Files
  For Each file in files
    wscript.echo file.name
    logFile.writeline(file.name)
  Next
logFile.close
```

Comment: Dan that is what I needed thanks for you help on this.

Comment: dir/b >fileNameLogs.txt