# Extract Sorted File Names By Alephabets

Tags: windows, vbscript

As you can know, you can sort files in windows explorer by their names, But it seems VBScript is not showing them in sorted way.

Here is a sample script which show file names in a folder one by one

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strReg = "C:\Users\Smart\Desktop\Files"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strReg)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    WScript.Echo ObjFile.Path
Next
```

But it seems it is showing files in random ways. How Can I edit this script to show files just as they are sorted in windows explorer?

Just note that My Files' Names are unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the FileSystemObject can't sort the files (cf. the citation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895790/603855)), you'll have to write (not edit) your own code. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210126/603855) for a sample using an ArrayList (and a list of alternative approaches). The first link shows how to use `dir /A:-D /B /O:...`.

Comment: Thank You, I tested your second link's Script. But it seems it can not sort files just like windows explorer. What should I do? Your script is working just my script. It is listing files as they are listed my script!